# Error retrieving translation

Tags: android, android-layout, google-translate

May be this question is duplicate but I dont found any solution from old questions.

I want to translate language and I used `google-api-translate-java-0.97.jar`.

I used below code I got error like:

> com.google.api.GoogleAPIException: java.lang.Exception:
>   [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText MyInputText;
    Button MyTranslateButton;
    TextView MyOutputText;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputText);
        MyTranslateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TranslateButton);
        MyOutputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OutputText);

        MyTranslateButton.setOnClickListener(MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String InputString;
            String OutputString = null;
            InputString = MyInputText.getText().toString();

            try {


                GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://www.google.com");
                GoogleAPI.setKey("AIzaSyCr9C8xNq0uODvZMNH_0Jb7BZpBCZMagOo");

                OutputString = Translate.DEFAULT. execute(InputString, Language.ENGLISH,
                        Language.FILIPINO);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ex.printStackTrace();
                OutputString = "Error";
            }

            MyOutputText.setText(OutputString);

        }

    };

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="hello"
 />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/InputText"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/TranslateButton"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Translate"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/OutputText"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

the program is right ,maybe it's a problem that you don't know news .Google announced it will close to multiple apis, including translation.
maybe it can help you http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/28/google-pinpoints-shutdown-dates-for-wave-translate-apis-amongs/